# Javascript игнорирует функцию. Пишу прототип ИИ для игры крестики-нолики. Не работает функция boter()

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function boter() {
  if ((game[0] == 1) && (game[4] == 0) && (count % 2 == 1)) {
    game[4]++;
    document.getElementById("fifth").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("fifth_o").style.display = "block";

  }
}

function game1() {
  count++;
  if ((count % 2 == 1) && (game_[0] == 0)) {
    game_[0]++;
    prototype[0][0] = 1;
    document.getElementById("first").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("first_x").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    game_[0]++;
    prototype[0][0] = 0;
    document.getElementById("first").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("first_o").style.display = "block";
  }
  check();
  boter();
}
```

Comment: почему ты думаешь,что она не работает?

Comment: не знаю что там с функцией. но вот постоянно вызывать `getElementById` не стоит

Comment: у меня на этом вся игра стоит. Почему так нельзя делать?